# Getting the src of the image active in a carousel of images

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

as the title says i want to get the src of the active image in a carousel of images right now my code is this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myCarousel1").on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
        var ele = $('.carousel-inner .item .active').val('.carousel - inner.item.active').toString();
        var totalItems = $('.item').text().length;
        //for (var i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) {
        //    var valeur = $('.item').index(i);
        //    console.log('balkchi n: ' + valeur
        //    );
        //}
        console.log('target: ' + totalItems);
        alert(totalItems);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Description", "Experience")',
            data: { 'Activite': totalItems },
            type: "post",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loadpartial").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your function:

```
var imageSrc = $('.active').find('img').attr('src');
console.log(imageSrc);
```

Comment: thank u man it worked i got the src path of img